# Blank page after pressing submit

Tags: php, laravel

I have form with multiple rows and I want to save into DB some columns of every row, but when I press submit I get blank page and there is no errors.
My form:

```html
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['updateHelper'], 'method' => 'POST','id'=>'beforeSubmitO']) !!} 
        <table class="table table-striped operatives" id="checkTableO" dir="rtl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>                             
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                    <th>XXX</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myDIV">
                @foreach($operatives as $operative)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="selected"><a href="{{route('showHelper',['id'=>$operative->id,'emp_id'=>$operative->employee_no])}}" onclick="myscrollfun()" >
                                {{$operative->employee_no}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{$operative->employee_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->start_date_of_work}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->company}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->termination_reason}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->termination_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->position_change}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->position}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->position_percent}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->change_base_salary}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->before_previous_month}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->previous_month}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->current_month}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->gross_difference}}</td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->net}}</td>
                        <td>{{$operative->risk_level}}</td>
                        <td><textarea class="comment" id="comment" type="text" name="comment[]" rows="1" cols="23">{{$operative->comment}}</textarea></td>
                        <td><input {{old('is_proper[]',$operative->isproper)=="V"? 'checked':''}} type="checkbox" class="isproper"  name="is_proper[]" value="V" /></td>
                        <td><input {{old('is_proper[]',$operative->isproper)=="X"? 'checked':''}} type="checkbox" class="isnotproper" name="is_proper[]" value="X" /></td>                                    
                        <td>
                            <select class="check" name="rescoring[]">
                                <option {{old('rescoring[]',$operative->rescoring)=="לא"? 'selected':''}} value="לא" selected>לא</option>
                                <option {{old('rescoring[]',$operative->rescoring)=="כן"? 'selected':''}} value="כן">כן</option> 
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td dir="ltr">{{$operative->user_name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="oper_id[]" value="{{$operative->id}}"></td>
                        <td><input class="checkboxVal" type="hidden" name="checkbox_val[]" value=''></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                    <p class="row justify-content-center pagination">{{$operatives->links()}}</p> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary float-right','id'=>'save', 'onclick'=>'myscrollfun()'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My route:

```
Route::put('/operatives',[
    'as' => 'updateHelper',
    'uses' => 'OperativesController@update'
]);
```

Controller update function:

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $oper_id = $request->oper_id;
        $comment = $request->comment;
        $rescoring = $request->rescoring;
        $checkboxVal = $request->checkbox_val;

        foreach($oper_id as $key => $value){
            $operative = Operative::find($value);
            $operative->comment = $comment[$key];
            $operative->rescoring = $rescoring[$key];
            if($checkboxVal[$key] == ''){
                $operative->isproper = '';  
            }
            else{
                $operative->isproper = $checkboxVal[$key];
            }

            $operative->save();
        }

        return back()->with('success','Updated'); 
    }
```

On localhost everything works just fine, but on server it is shows blank page.

I tried to check my php.ini on server - "post_max_size" and "max_input_vars", but it is the same like on localhost.

Does anyone have any idea why? what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check log file on production?

Comment: This is the last row : C:\\inetpub\\leapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 C:\\inetpub\\leapp\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#63 {main}
"}

Answer (score 2):

The reason nothing is displaying is because you're not actually redirect back. You need to call the `back()` method on the `redirect()` helper (or on the `Redirect` model).

In your `update()` method, replace

```
return back()->with('success','Updated');
```

With

```php
return redirect()->back()->with('success','Updated');
```

You should also specify that the form handles a `PUT` request, which you can do by setting the `method` attribute in your form to `'PUT'` instead of `'POST'`.

```
'method' => 'PUT'
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and still get blank page :/

Comment: You can try to use a `POST` request (so remove the `put` and replace it by `post` in the route, in the form, and then remove `{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}`. You don't seem to pass the put-request for a specific model, so you can try to `POST` it instead.

Comment: i tried this too but it is do not help. finally I found the solution -  changed max_post_size and max_input_vars in php.ini and that solved my problem! TNX